# How to delete the non empty directory in treeview using c#

Tags: c#

I am using the TreeView to show directory structures and I need to be able to delete non empty folders.

```
System.IO.Directory.Delete(TreeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath);
```

The above code works fine for deleting empty folders, but I need to delete non empty folders, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Directory.Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method takes an optional second boolean parameter which indicates if you want to delete its contents. Just add `true` as the second parameter:

```
System.IO.Directory.Delete(TreeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if directory is empty or not ?

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(TreeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath).Count() > 0)
{
    Directory.Delete(TreeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath, true);
}
```

Comment: if you need to ensure, that directory is not empty, you don't need to count files, you just need to know, that there is at least one (use `Any()`)

Answer (score 0):

To delete folders, files with sub-folders, try this

```
private void DeleteDirectory(string path)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        //Delete all files from the Directory
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
        //Delete all child Directories
        foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
           DeleteDirectory(directory);
        }
        //Delete a Directory
        Directory.Delete(path);
    }
}
```

Call

```
string path = "yourPath";
DeleteDirectory(path);
```